# Can't get the Get ajax working

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

when  I look at the  header sent  by the test.php in Chrome inspector it says `action : startjson` but  I cant  retrieve   this  variable `$_GET['action']`, the  array is empty.

test.php :

```
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#testjson").click(function(e){
        startJsonSession();
        return false;
    });

    function startJsonSession(){  
        $.ajax({
            url: "test2.php?action=startjson",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(data) {
                username = data.username;
                alert(username);
            }

    });
    }

    }); 
    </script>
    <button id="testjson">
    toto
    </button>
</body>
```

test2.php :

```
    <?php 
    if ($_GET['action'] == "startjson") { 
            startjsonSession(); 
        } 

        function startjsonSession() {
            $items = '';

            print json_encode(array(
                "username" => "bob",
                "items" => array(
                    "item1" => "sandwich",
                    "item2" => "applejuice"
                )
            ));
        }
```

Comment: What's the status of the request?

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between sucess and complete , The complete function does not receive the 'data' parameter, so if your action depends on the data then it won't work there.

Complete : complete callback option fires, when the request finishes, whether in failure or success. It receives the jqXHR object, as well as a string containing the success or error code.

Success : callback option is invoked, if the request succeeds. It receives the returned data, a string containing the success code, and the jqXHR object.